# increase c++ code verbosity with macros

Tags: c++, debugging, macros

I'd like to have the possibility to increase the verbosity for debug purposes of my program. Of course I can do that using a switch/flag during runtime. But that can be very inefficient, due to all the 'if' statements I should add to my code.

So, I'd like to add a flag to be used during compilation in order to include optional, usually slow debug operations in my code, without affecting the performance/size of my program when not needed. here's an example:

```
/* code */
#ifdef _DEBUG_
/* do debug operations here 
#endif
```

so, compiling with -D_DEBUG_ should do the trick. without it, that part won't be included in my program.

Another option (at least for i/o operations) would be to define at least an i/o function, like

```
#ifdef _DEBUG_
#define LOG(x) std::clog << x << std::endl;
#else
#define LOG(x) 
#endif
```

However, I strongly suspect this probably isn't the cleanest way to do that. So, what would you do instead?

Comment: I would say this is very much a case of personal preference.

Comment: Actually, conditional compilation which you are using looks like the cleanest way for C/C++. There might be some template parameter matching tricks for C++, but the will definitely increase the compilation time and with a non-decent compiler some of the symbols might increase your executable.

Comment: I note a potential source of obscure bugs with your suggestion, which is also why sftrabbit's answer is a good one: your `LOG(x)` differs in whether it defines a statement with `_DEBUG_` on and off meaning that `if (whatever) LOG(x)` behaves differently depending on whether `_DEBUG_` is defined. If you do go the macro route be careful to avoid this kind of error.

Comment: Following up on @Jack's note the correct definition for the non-debugging version is `#define LOG(x) ;` or something similar. Even very primitive compiler can optimize away empty statements. The *really* careful approach uses `do{}while(0);`.

Comment: @dmckee: personally I prefer to omit the `;` from the `_DEBUG_` defined version so you write `LOG(x);` in the usual fashion but it makes little difference.

Answer (score 19):

I prefer to use `#ifdef` with real functions so that the function has an empty body if `_DEBUG_` is not defined:

```
void log(std::string x)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG_
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

There are three big reasons for this preference:

1. When `_DEBUG_` is not defined, the function definition is empty and any modern compiler will completely optimize out any call to that function (the definition should be visible inside that translation unit, of course).
2. The `#ifdef` guard only has to be applied to a small localized area of code, rather than every time you call `log`.
3. You do not need to use lots of macros, avoiding pollution of your code.

Comment: thanks for this answer. let me get this straight: so, whenever _DEBUG_ is not defined, the compiler will simply ignore the call to the log function?

Comment: @MarcDuQuesne Almost certainly. The compiler will see that the function has no effect and just leave it out completely.

Comment: Only assuming the compiler sees the definition! (Or does LTO, but that's the exception rather than the rule at this time.) If the definition is in a different TU the compiler can't know that it has no effect while it compiles your code.

Comment: Note that compiler can't necessarily optimize out the logging statement if the argument is more than a simple variable.  E.g., if you say `log("Trying to frooble "+myfrooble.to_string())` then the (potentially expensive) `myfrooble.to_string()` method still gets called.  Contrast this with the OP's `LOG` macro, where the call *would* get removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use macros to change implementation of the function (Like in sftrabbit's solution). That way, no empty places will be left in your code, and the compiler will optimize the "empty" calls away.

You can also use two distinct files for the debug and release implementation, and let your IDE/build script choose the appropriate one; this involves no `#defines` at all. Just remember the DRY rule and make the clean code reusable in debug scenario.

I would say that his actually is very dependent on the actual problem you are facing. Some problems will benefit more of the second solution, whilst the simple code might be better with simple defines.

Answer (score 2):

Both snippets that you describe are correct ways of using conditional compilation to enable or disable the debugging through a compile-time switch. However, your assertion that checking the debug flags at runtime "can be very inefficient, due to all the 'if' statements I should add to my code" is mostly incorrect: in most practical cases a runtime check does not influence the speed of your program in a detectable way, so if keeping the runtime flag offers you potential advantages (e.g. turning the debugging on to diagnose a problem in production without recompiling) you should go for a run-time flag instead.

Answer (score 1):

For the additional checks, I would rely on the assert (see the [assert.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/)) which does exactly what you need: check when you compile in debug, no check when compiled for the release.

For the verbosity, a more C++ version of what you propose would use a simple Logger class with a boolean as template parameter. But the macro is fine as well if kept within the Logger class.

Answer (score 1):

For commercial software, having SOME debug output that is available at runtime on customer sites is usually a valuable thing to have. I'm not saying everything has to be compiled into the final binary, but it's not at all unusual that customers do things to your code that you don't expect [or that causes the code to behave in ways that you don't expect]. Being able to tell the customer "Well, if you run `myprog -v 2 -l logfile.txt` and do you usual thing, then email me `logfile.txt`" is a very, very useful thing to have.

As long as the "if-statement to decide if we log or not" is not in the deepest, darkest jungle in peru, eh, I mean in the deepest nesting levels of your tight, performance critical loop, then it's rarely a problem to leave it in.

So, I personally tend to go for the "always there, not always enabled" approach. THat's not to say that I don't find myself adding some extra logging in the middle of my tight loops sometimes - only to remove it later on when the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the function-like macro when doing conditional compilation. Just define a regular or template function to do the logging and call it inside the:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG_
/* ... */
#endif
```

part of the code.

Comment: this would imply a lot of #ifdef ... #endif blocks inside the code, which you may want to avoid. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are completely right, if the only operation you want to accomplish is logging.

Answer (score 0):

An example piece of code I use in my projects. This way, you can use variable argument list and if *DEBUG* flag is not set, related code is cleared out:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define PR_DEBUG(fmt, ...) \
    PR_DEBUG(fmt, ...) printf("[DBG] %s: " fmt, __func__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define PR_DEBUG(fmt, ...)
#endif
```

Usage:

```
#define DEBUG
<..>
ret = do_smth();
PR_DEBUG("some kind of code returned %d", ret);
```

Output:

```
[DBG] some_func: some kind of code returned 0
```

of course, `printf()` may be replaced by any output function you use. Furthermore, it can be easily modified so additional information, as for example time stamp, is automatically appended.

Comment: That should be `#define PR_DEBUG(fmt, ...)` in the "not debug" case. Otherwise the preprocessor will leave `("some kind of code returned %d", ret);` for the compiler to probably complain about.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, yes you are right, forgot to copy it. Answer edited, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the *Nix universe, the default define for this kind of thing is `NDEBUG` (read *no-debug*). If it is defined, your code should skip the debug code. I.e. you would do something like this:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
inline void log(...) {}
#else
inline void log(...) { .... }
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it depends from application to application.

I've had applications where I wanted to always log (for example, we had an application where in case of errors, clients would take all the logs of the application and send them to us for diagnostics). In such a case, the logging API should probably be based on functions (i.e. not macros) and always defined.

In cases when logging is not always necessary or you need to be able to completely disable it for performance/other reasons, you can define logging macros.

In that case I prefer a single-line macro like this:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define LOGSTREAM /##/
#else
#define LOGSTREAM std::clog
// or
// #define LOGSTREAM std::ofstream("output.log", std::ios::out|std::ios::app)
#endif
```

client code:

```
LOG << "Initializing chipmunk feeding module ...\n";
//...
LOG << "Shutting down chipmunk feeding module ...\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just like any other feature.

My assumptions:

- No global variables
- System designed to interfaces

For whatever you want verbose output, create two implementations, one quiet, one verbose.
At application initialisation, choose the implementation you want.

It could be a logger, or a widget, or a memory manager, for example.

Obviously you don't want to duplicate code, so extract the minimum variation you want. If you know what the strategy pattern is, or the decorator pattern, these are the right direction. Follow the open closed principle.